# IMAP and Office 365 Email in One domain

Tags: domain, microsoft-office-365, imap

I have been hosting a site for a client for 4 years and this year they Added Office 365 to the domain.  When we put in the DNS records, all of the IMAP accounts I had stopped working.  Is there a way to keep the domain specific IMAP accounts along with Office 365?  The accounts were admin and support for customers of the clients site.  To continue to use those IMAP accounts, I have to use THEIR Office 365 which I prefer not to do (I am a contractor for the company).

Any thoughts on how to amend DNS to allow for both Office 365 and domain IMAP?

Answer (score 0):

yeah absolutely.  The easiest way would be to add a subdomain and alias the accounts at the root domain to the subdomain accounts.  You can still send from those accounts + o265 as long as both systems are included in the spf records.

so at o365:

support@example.org forward mail to support@legacy.example.com. (can be a contact or a distro group with a single member) (may have dmarc/spf issues if o365 doesn't do from address rewriting)

add mx records at legacy (or an A record will suffice) to point mail to that older server.

another option is to use pop3 Downloader or imapsync for the 2 accounts but you will need a license for that.

You can also do this with transport rules.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj950234(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Your answer is the best, but as a contractor (the OP), that imply someone will have to keep maintaining that old server.

Comment: I assume he wants to maintain the old server, "Is there a way to keep the domain specific IMAP accounts along with Office 365? " another option is dual-delivery, which I've only heard of Google apps allowing (I wrote a blog post about it)

Answer (score -1):

Use their O365, as you can access your account there in IMAP if its your need, check the link below. For the MX, no with the MX pointing to O365 you will have to use it, and usually the SPF will be secured to allow only sender from O365.

nb, My answer assume, as you are a contractor, that its them that want you to use their O365. If such, dont try to bypass them and talk to them if you want to bring another solution to bypass their O365. (As in example they might want to host all data, and having email/information going to a server not in their control might be a deal breaker)

The IMAP reference;

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c

Comment: Forgot to follow up with you guys - thanks for the insights.  We had them create O365 accounts.  The problem is the client ran O365 on a web-server and did not even bother to see if the server could support a burgeoning office system.  It consumed their bandwidth and now they have a slow office system.  Convincing them to upgrade the server is like talking to a wall.